# Checkboxes with hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using `CheckboxFormatter` plugin with hierarchical data. The problem is that if I check a collapsed group and then expand it, the child rows are not selected by default (`selectedCellCssClass` is not applied). I am pretty new to using SlickGrid. But this is how I assume the control should be flowing:

1. There must be a 'hidden' attribute associated with each row when a checkbox formatter is used. Clicking the checkbox would simply toggle this attribute to true/false.
2. Clicking checkbox should raise an onClick/onChecked event which can be overridden.
3. In the event, one can check to see if the checked row has children, if yes, then set the 'hidden' attribute on the children.
4. Apply the css on checked rows.

If anyone can point me to the specific events, attributes used, that would act as a great starting point. Also the steps I have mentioned are just a guess :D Any help on actual process will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as you (I'm trying to check all rows in a group). I'm assuming you are using groups right? Do you have a checkbox in the group header? and if you do does the checkbox toggle? I've been having a lot of trouble with his too.

Comment: @eric, I have found a workaround for now. I ended up giving my own checkbox implementation without using the CheckboxFormatter. So, whenever I would check a parent, I would set an attribute for all children recursively, then override getItemmetadata to return a specific css class for all such children.

Comment: Hmm that sounds interesting. Would you be willing to supply the code for it? I'd like to check it out.

Comment: I am posting the code as a possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up giving my own checkbox implementation without using `CheckboxFormatter`. I added a `checked` property to my data model and whenever a row would be checked, I recursively changed the state of all affected rows.

```
var
     $target = $(event.target),
     isChecked = $target.is(":checked"),
     id = dataContext['id'],
     item = dataView.getItemById(id),
     children = getChildren(id), // helper method to get children for curr
     parent = getParent(id); // helper method to get parent for curr


 dataContext['checked'] = isChecked;
 dataView.updateItem(dataContext['id'], dataContext);

// loop through all children recursively
 while (children && children.length > 0) {
      var item = children.shift();
      item.checked = isChecked;
      dataView.updateItem(item.id, item);
      var _children = getChildren(item.id);
      if (_children && _children.length > 0)
           children = [].slice.call(_children).concat(children);
 }
 // traverse up the hierarchy
 while (parent && parent.id != config.currentUser) {
        if (!isChecked) {
             parent.checked = isChecked
             dataView.updateItem(parent.id, parent);
        } else {
             // if all siblings are checked, change state of parent.
              var siblingsChecked = true;
              $.each(getChildren(parent.id), function (index, item) {
              if (!item.checked)
                    siblingsChecked = false;
              }); 
              if (siblingsChecked) {
                   parent.checked = isChecked;
                   dataView.updateItem(parent.id, parent);
              }
         }
          parent = dataView.getItemById(parent.parentId);
  }
```

I then had to override the getItemMetaData method to return a specific css class for all checked rows.

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function (index) {
     var item = dataView.getItem(index);
     if (item.checked === true) {
         return { cssClasses: 'slick-row-selected' };
      }
};
```